# Angular V9 Async pipe not updating template view on data change

Tags: typescript, angular2-template, angular2-pipe, rxjs-observables, async-pipe

I'm pretty much a standstill with this now guys. I'm using a small service to get the details from an API, returning a JSON object. I am returning this as an Observable from the service method; then initialising the local component variable "sateliteData$" with it on class creation.

In the HTML I'm trying to use the | async pipe to handle automatic change detection as the values from this API, change every second. But when looking at my application, it gets the first set of values and displays them to the screen, but never updates them.

You have to manually refresh the page to get different values, which is what I'm trying to avoid by using Observables and the | async pipe.

I've read so much online, and everything I'm doing seems to match what everyone else does. I just can't figure this out and would really appreciate someone taking the time to have a look at this for me.

See below screen grabs of the code.

Thanks guys.

[image: r]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would be to poll the server at a fixed interval. You can achieve this using rxjs

```
polling$ = interval(2000).pipe(switchMap(_ => this.service.MyGetRequest()));
```

You can see a minimal working stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ebebp4

More information on simple polling here: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/recipes/http-polling

Take care if you are polling an external service or API that you do not own that you do not flood them with requests. Look at their documentation to determine what is or is not an appropriate interval.

Comment: My understanding of the Async pipe is that it subscribes to an observable for you, and listens for changes in the data stream. And thus updates your template view with the new data.

Would it not be redundant to create a manual interval for the request and negate the use of the pipe altogether? New to the pipe so I'm just basing this off minimal research rather than practical experience.

Comment: @LewisMorgans using the async pipe does indeed handle the subscription for you. The issue you are running into is the fact that your observable only sends one request to your server, after which it is in a resolved state. 

The server you requested a value from is not aware of your observable in any way, so you will never receive another response on that observable, until you explicitly call the api again.

Comment: The way you have explained that makes perfect sense. Thanks for taking the time to clear that up for me. I've been under the impression though, when working with Observable types, such as HTTP/XHR requests that as long as the observable is not destroyed, it remains open?

Is there something built into the angular httpclientmodule that destroys the observable once data is received?